# Pointer syntax in C

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, what is the correct syntax for declaring pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280729/in-c-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-declaring-pointers)
>   [good way to write “pointer to something” in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016117/good-way-to-write-pointer-to-something-in-c-c)

I am currently reading a book on C. At the moment I read about pointers.

Basically, I think that I have understood the concept. Anyway one thing puzzles me:

Sometimes the author uses

```
void *foo;
```

to create a new pointer, but sometimes it's

```
void* foo;
```

Is there a difference? Does it matter? Doesn't it? When to use what? ...?

Comment: No technical difference. Doesn't stop people arguing about it for all eternity though. In the end it's just a personal preference.

Comment: Just remember that the `*` binds to the *declarator*, not the type specifier; IOW, `void* foo;` is parsed as `void (*foo);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many or as few spaces either side of the * as you like. It means exactly the same thing either way:

```
void*foo;
void *foo;
void* foo;
void * foo;
void                     * foo;
void *                     foo;
void           *           foo;
```

All are exactly the same thing. If you work on a project, there is usually some "coding style standard" that explains which is preferred in that project. But the compiler won't do any different based on if/where there are spaces.

Comment: No they are not exactly the last example has a typo. SCNR.

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent but the former can be preferable when declaring multiple variables of non-void type in a single line

```
int *foo, *bar;
```

clearly declares two pointers, while

```
int* foo, bar;
```

declares one pointer and one `int`

Answer (score 2):

Both are equivalent and no difference whatsoever.

```
int *foo, i;
```

But you should know the difference in declarations like above. Here only `foo` is of pointer type whereas `i` is of type `int` (not `int*`).

Answer (score 1):

The two syntaxes are equivalent. The only difference is a matter of style.

Comment: Look at the other similar answers. This answer is technically correct, but very terse. If you're going to answer a duplicate at least make it a good answer, not just the bare minimum which overlooks the important point. Your answer says *less* than my comment.

Comment: @Flexo: When I've posted this (and when the downote appeared), there were no longer answers. There is no definitive answer to such questions. Therefore I think these "explanations" are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference to compiler, as you probably already know.

As of the matter of style, some argue that `void* ptr` is better because the type name as a whole is isolated. The problem is, that's not how the *language* works:

```
int*  ptr, otherptr; /* otherptr is not a pointer here */
```

Even if you decide against declaring multiple variables at once, the whole idea of having an isolated type name breaks for arrays and function pointers. That's why I prefer the other style:

```
int *ptr, *otherptr, dontDeclareTooManyThings[N];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference?

Of course there is. (If there wasn't, you wouldn't be asking this.) The star is on one side of the whitespace in the first case, and on the other side in the other.

> Does it matter?

It does. Not in terms of program logic, however - the two are parsed exactly the same way. However, it's a matter of personal preference. I generally **recommend the second way,** i. e. `void *ptr`, since the pointer qualifier (the asterisk) modifies the variable, and not the type.

> When to use what?

Just explained.

Comment: The asterisk can be viewed also as the type modifier. Hence you can read `void* ptr` as "type of ptr is void pointer", i.e pointer to anything, later type-cast to the exact type pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Both variants are valid.
They represent different styles.

consider

```
char* foo, bar;
char *foo, bar;
```

in both cases foo is a pointer, bar is not.

also consider (readability)

```
char* foo() {
    // return something
}
```